# How do I see if my GPUImage Video was recorded in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, gpuimage

I followed this guide on how to record video using the `GPUStillImage` library:

http://www.cocoanetics.com/2014/06/object-overlay-on-video/

However my implementation is different since I'm using the `GPUImageVideoCamera` to record video and and using `GPUImageMovieWriter` to write it. Unfortunately unlike the demo project in the tutorial, the `setCompletion` block is not firing and it doesn't save the file into my albums. How do I know if it worked successfully? Is there a way to open up the directory on my iPhone to see that the movie was successfully recorded? Thanks!

Comment: I guess there is problem with your path. NSlog your pathToMovie and show what it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to just do this instead

```
[self.movieWriter finishRecording];
UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum([NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/Movie.m4v"] , nil, nil, nil);
```

And like magic it appeared in my Photo Album. For whatever reason, the `setCompletion` block never fired but I guess you don't need to rely on it.